# Navigation drawer onClick in items ripple effect lost

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, onitemclicklistener

Using the new appcompat-v21 I try to build a navigation drawer.. The first time I didn't write any background color or drawable and the navigation drawer started with a transparent background!! So strange! But, when I clicked in the items of it I could see the ripple effect of Android lollipop. (Amazing). So I tried to put a white background like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

     <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navdrawer"
            android:layout_width="315dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#ffff"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The navigation drawer now is white and so it's correct. But with this background I lost the ripple effect in the item click. My item XML is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinnerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sfondomappa"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/banner_nav" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/drawerWelcome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sfondomappa"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="#40000000"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hola"
                android:textColor="@color/ldrawer_color"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawerTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/main_orange"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="3dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_itemName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="#E4000000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I even wrote this `android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"` in my root layout but nothing change.. How can I solve?

EDIT:
I wrote again the listview of my drawer in this way

```
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navdrawer"
            android:layout_width="315dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#00000000"
            android:dividerHeight="1.00dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
```

and the ripple works. But now i lost the current position i clicked.

Comment: did you find the solution? I have the same problem as well..

Comment: @VamsiChalla i have solved partially..i can show the ripple on click but i can't "save" the current position. See the edit

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same problem ... the solution is not documented good enough, but here it is.

Create a selector drawable in your `drawable-v21` folder:

```
    v21/activated_background.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@color/primary_dark" android:state_activated="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@color/primary" android:state_checked="true" />
        <item android:state_pressed="true">
            <ripple android:color="@color/primary" />
        </item>
        <item android:drawable="@color/background_light" />
    </selector>
```

As you can see in the code above, the magic is done by adding the `<ripple ... />` element above. It's available in v21+ only, so that's why you have to declare separate selectors for -v21 and normal.

Lastly, just put this selector drawable as background of the desired element, in your case the ListView item.

Comment: This crashes with "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class <unknown>"

Comment: Are you sure that's used in v21 folder? I doubt those specific lines cause the exception, as they work perfectly for me in 2 different projects :)

Comment: I withdraw my comment. It was in v21 but now after futzing that problem is gone, I'm not sure why. There may have been some extra character in there.

Comment: However, when in a selector, the ripple doesn't look/act like it should. First time I press it, it's solid and gets darker. Second time, it doesn't appear at all...